# Why does angular prefix redirect url with 'localhost' when using $location.path?

Tags: angularjs

The following snippet of code doesn't redirect me to the specified page (`redirectUrl`) - but rather, prefixes redirectUrl with the string 'localhost'.

I end up redirected to `"localhost/http://localhost/example/page".`

How can I avoid this?

```
var redirectUrl =  "http://localhost/example/page";
$location.path(redirectUrl); //redirects to "localhost/http://localhost/example/page".`
$scope.$apply();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify your path to a relative path rather than an absolute path. so it would be something like this:

```
var redirectUrl =  "/example/page";
$location.path(redirectUrl); //redirects to "http://localhost/example/page".`
```

Answer (score 0):

angular's `$location` service works based on relative url.

To redirect to absolute url you can use.

`window.location.href="http://localhost/example/page";`
or using angular's `$window`
`$window.location.href="http://localhost/example/page";`